# Convert Characters to Twips for Access ColumnWidth

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm maintaining some old VB6 software and need to set the width of an MS Access column programmatically based on the average number of field characters to display, like one can do from the Datasheet view in Access.

In VB, however, the value must be specified in Twips, and I'm having some difficulty converting between "number of characters" and Twips.

For example, if the font is Arial 10pt (96 DPI) and I specify "50 characters" in Access, the value is returned as "4530 Twips" via the `Properties("ColumnWidth")` method in VB. And if I specify "4530" via the `CreateProperty("ColumnWidth")` method in VB, "50" is displayed in Access.

Based on the [Column Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column%28v=office.14%29.aspx) spec for Office 2010, and the [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) spec, I'm using the following code to calculate the column width in Twips, but for the example above, the value of "5490" is returned instead:

**FORM**

```
'Identify normal style's font for Access
Dim Font As New StdFont
Font.Name = "Arial"
Font.Size = 10

'Calculate longest width of digits 0-9
Dim Digit As Integer
Dim MaxDigitWidth As Single
For Digit = 0 To 9
    Dim mdw As Single
    mdw = CalcTextWidth(Digit, Font)
    If mdw > MaxDigitWidth Then MaxDigitWidth = mdw
Next Digit

Dim MaxChars As Integer
Dim Width As Single, Pixels As Long, Twips As Long

'Identify number of characters to display horizontally
MaxChars = 50

'Adjust character value based on actual font metrics
Width = Int((MaxChars * MaxDigitWidth + 5) / MaxDigitWidth * 256) / 256

'Convert into screen resolution (TwipsPerPixelX = 1440 / 96 or 120 DPI)
Pixels = Int(((256 * Width + Int(128 / MaxDigitWidth)) / 256) * MaxDigitWidth)
Twips = Pixels * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
```

**MODULE**

```
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "Gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "Gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "Gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "Gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetTextExtentPoint32 Lib "Gdi32" Alias "GetTextExtentPoint32A" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal cbString As Long, lpSize As SIZE) As Long

Private Type SIZE
    cx As Long
    cy As Long
End Type

'Calculate width in pixels of screen text
Public Function CalcTextWidth(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Font As StdFont) As Single
    Dim myFont As IFont
    Dim hFont As Long
    Dim mySize As Size
    Dim hDC As Long

    'Clone font
    Set myFont = New StdFont
    myFont.Name = Font.Name

    'Increase precision since GetTextExtentPoint32 returns a Long
    myFont.Size = Font.Size * 1000

    'Set device context as screen display for font metrics
    hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0)

    'Calculate string width in pixels
    hFont = SelectObject(hDC, myFont.hFont)
    GetTextExtentPoint32 hDC, Source, Len(Source), mySize
    SelectObject hDC, hFont
    DeleteObject hFont
    DeleteDC hDC

    'Restore precision
    CalcTextWidth = mySize.cx / 1000
End Function
```

I also came across an [MS Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214123) article for how column widths are calculated in Excel, but the examples provided seem to conflict with the algorithms disclosed for Office.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

** **Update 3/20** **

Here's a simplified version of the code block that sets the `ColumnWidth` property using the `Font` and `Twips` defined previously:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim td As TableDef
Dim prop As Property

Set db = CreateDatabase("db1.mdb", dbLangGeneral)
Set td = db.CreateTableDef("Table1")
td.Fields.Append td.CreateField("Field1", dbMemo)
db.TableDefs.Append td

Set prop = td.CreateProperty("DatasheetFontName", dbText, Font.Name): td.Properties.Append prop
Set prop = td.CreateProperty("DatasheetFontHeight", dbInteger, Font.Size): td.Properties.Append prop
Set prop = td.Fields("Field1").CreateProperty("ColumnWidth", dbInteger, Twips): td.Fields("Field1").Properties.Append prop

db.Close
```

Also, not sure if it matters, but I'm using VB6 Service Pack 6 with the following references:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library
- Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Comment: Are these textboxes? Can you set the [columnwidth to -2](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Auto-fit-Column-Datashee-t1993006.html)?

Comment: I'm interested in setting the widths for fields when they are viewed as a Table object in Access. I considered specifying them as auto fit, but I'd prefer a hardcoded value for a consistent display.

Comment: Well if you want a hardcoded value you can use the designer, no? Seems overkill for hardcoding

Comment: Databases are created by VB.

Comment: This is tagged VB6.  Is at all actually Access VBA?  It makes a difference since the UI frameworks are not the same.

Comment: Nope, it is VB6. I'll expand the **FORM** code above to show how `ColumnWidth` is being set.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several APIs to compute column width, including `GetTextExtentPoint32`, `GetCharABCWidths` and others, as well as the built-in `TextWidth()` function, none of which yielded exact measurements due to rounding, I figured out a way to do so precisely using an **Excel Object**.

In Excel, a column has **two** width properties: `ColumnWidth` and `Width`.

`ColumnWidth` is the number of character units to display horizontally based on the maximum width of digits 0-9 for the Normal style font. So if a value of "50" is defined and 50 zeros are entered in cell A1, all digits will be visible.

`Width` is the `ColumnWidth` value retranslated into pixels for the Normal style font.

It is noteworthy that setting the `ColumnWidth` for an Excel spreadsheet via VB6 can be done in character units; conversely, `ColumnWidth` for an Access table must be in twips.

Moreover, the Normal style font for Excel can be changed, whereas there doesn't seem to be a way to do so for Access -- a default font can be set for a Datasheet, but this isn't the same as the Normal style font.

For example, if Arial 10 pt is defined and wrapping is to occur at 50 characters, it would seem logical that a value of 50 character units should be specified; however, **58.8333** must actually be defined in Access. Furthermore, even if the registry keys `Default Font Name` and `Default Font Size` are set to the desired font, Access appears to be using hardcoded font metrics as the basis for its calculations.

My code below shows how to use an Excel Object to calculate the `ColumnWidth` for Access by having Excel perform the character units-to-pixel conversion. It also shows how to calculate the row height for a cell so that a certain number of lines are shown without clipping.

Note that Excel must be installed on the same workstation as VB6 and that references must include the *Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88

'########################################################################

'Calculate height for an MS Access cell
Private Function AccessHeight(ByVal MaxLines As Long) As Single

    'Set number of lines to display without clipping (based on leading of Normal style font)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim txt As String
    For i = 1 To MaxLines: txt = txt & "H" & IIf(i < MaxLines, vbCrLf, ""): Next

    'Measure height of lines (in twips); compensate for gridline padding
    '(note that device context is screen display since TextHeight a property of Form1)
    AccessHeight = TextHeight(txt) + 30
End Function

'########################################################################

'Calculate width for an MS Access cell
Private Function AccessWidth(ByVal MaxChars As Long) As Long
    Dim hDC, dpiX As Long
    Dim Excel, Workbook, Worksheet As Object
    Dim pixelsX As Single

    'Set device context as screen display and calculate horizontal DPI (96 or 120)
    hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0)
    dpiX = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
    DeleteDC hDC

    '#-------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Launch Excel as a system process
    Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add
    Set Worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets.Add

    'Initialize Normal style so that one unit of column width equals width of one character
    With Workbook.Styles("Normal").Font
        .Name = Font.Name
        .Size = Font.Size
        .Bold = Font.Bold
        .Italic = Font.Italic
        .Underline = Font.Underline
        .Strikethrough = Font.Strikethrough
    End With

    '#-------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Set number of characters to display horizontally without wrapping (based on maximum width of digits 0-9)
    Worksheet.Cells(1, 1).ColumnWidth = MaxChars

    'Instruct Excel to convert from character units into screen pixels
    pixelsX = Worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Width * dpiX / 72

    'Convert screen pixels into twips
    AccessWidth = Int(pixelsX * 1440 / dpiX)

    'Kill system process
    Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Excel.Quit
End Function

'########################################################################

Private Sub Form_Load()

    'Identify Normal style font
    With Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = False
        .Strikethrough = False
    End With

    '#-------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim db As Database
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim prop As Property
    Dim i As Integer

    'Create database
    ChDrive App.Path: ChDir App.Path
    Set db = CreateDatabase("db1.mdb", dbLangGeneral)
    Set td = db.CreateTableDef("Table1")
    td.Fields.Append td.CreateField("Field1", dbMemo)
    db.TableDefs.Append td

    'Set font
    Set prop = td.CreateProperty("DatasheetFontName", dbText, Font.Name): td.Properties.Append prop
    Set prop = td.CreateProperty("DatasheetFontHeight", dbInteger, Font.Size): td.Properties.Append prop

    'Set row height
    Dim MaxLines As Long
    MaxLines = 9
    Set prop = td.CreateProperty("RowHeight", dbInteger, AccessHeight(MaxLines)): td.Properties.Append prop

    'Set column width
    Dim MaxChars As Long
    MaxChars = 50
    Set prop = td.Fields("Field1").CreateProperty("ColumnWidth", dbInteger, AccessWidth(MaxChars)): td.Fields("Field1").Properties.Append prop

    'Add a record
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
    rs.AddNew
    For i = 1 To MaxLines: rs!Field1 = rs!Field1 & String$(MaxChars, CStr(i)) & IIf(i < MaxLines, vbCrLf, ""): Next
    rs.Update
    rs.Close

    db.Close
    End
End Sub
```